# Regular expression to match char and number

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a regular expression that tests for the following, something that starts with abc or def, followed by a number between 0 and 900, then can have anything between that, up until the nearest. I have found the code on net. how will  i change it according to my condition:

```
/\b[Z][0-9]{3,5}/
```

Comment: can you provide some of the code you are using or found? Would help to solve your problem!

Comment: i have already provided the code fount on net. i dont know to change it according to my condition. this is the code i have found on net : 
/\b[Z][0-9]{3,5}/

Comment: Do you mean you want this: `((abc)|(def))[0-9]{1,3}.*` ? What do you mean by *"then can have anything between that, up until the nearest"*?

Comment: @Matt i want to match only abc followed by 0-999 nubers

Comment: You actually have `0-900` in your question.

Comment: you want "abc" or "def" followed by any number between 0 and 999? or anywhere between 0 and 999 digits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression start with some string followed by number and end with spacial character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990979/regular-expression-start-with-some-string-followed-by-number-and-end-with-spacia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(abc|def)([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])?[0-9]$/
```

Seems to solve it for me.

Comment: Testing this, I only get abc or def followed by 2 digits, and only if it's an entire word - I think you can get rid of the `^` and `$`

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/npbxc/ It does seem to miss the "non" matches, but it also matches on the parts (note, I'm not a regex expert, this may be explainable).

Comment: @Matt - What you're saying gives a different result, as well as matching on a non-match row (AFAICT): http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/npbxc/1/

Comment: I ran it through [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) and it only highlighted two of the three numbers, and only if it was the entire string; not just part of a string

Answer (score 1):

```
/(abc|def)(([0-9])|([0-9][0-9]{0,1})|([0-8][0-9]{0,2})|(900))($|[^0-9][^(abc|def)]*)/
```

Gets any "abc" or "def" followed by numbers between 0 and 900, followed by at least one non-digit, followed by anything up until the next "abc" or "def". Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @JaredFarrish run the updated regex through [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/). It works.

Comment: I had the wrong technology: http://codepad.org/tBVBiCzH Check my code, but at least in PHP, it's not giving any matches. Regex is usually language-dependent, so a tool may not always be accurate.

Comment: Yeah, regexpal isn't the best. I found another one at http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm and it uses PHP's `preg_match` and `preg_match_all` functions. Try that one out.

Comment: I did have a couple of errors and PCRE seems to be broken on codepad. So, here's Viper 7: http://codepad.viper-7.com/s9JNJN It seems to be giving submatches. Not sure if that's intended.

Comment: Yes, I thought that's what OP wanted. For example it'll extract `abc834salkjasfdef283kdsl` into `abc834salkjasf` and `def283kdsl`

Comment: Yeah, I don't know; the OP certainly wasn't real clear. `+1` for effort and for trying to match `0-900`.

Comment: It was "interesting" to put that regex together.

Comment: This will match abc000 correct? I dunno if leading zeros are ok or not.

Comment: @aquinas OP never said one way or another :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
\a\{1,3}\d\{1,3}
```

Please Try that. It matches upto 3 alpha and upto three digits

```
\(abc\)\|\(def\)\d\{1,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(abc|def)(900|0|[1-8]?[0-9]{0,2})$
```

Comment: I ran it through regexpal. Yes it does.

Comment: Er...ok. I just ran it through regexpal too, and it looks like it works to me. More importantly, look at the javascript fiddle. Pretty clearly it doesn't match. :)

Comment: I see that. So which one is comparing regexes per PHP? That's the question we have to answer.

Comment: [this one tests via php `preg_match` and `preg_match_all`](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm)